# cartopy shapefile turning out as a dot

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I'm trying to shift over from basemap to cartopy, and im experiencing some difficulties in plotting a simple shapefile.

Using basemap I can get this

[image]

Code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
# define map extent
lllat=1.1497
urlat=1.5133
lllon=103.5822
urlon=104.1579

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(
    projection = 'merc',
    llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat,
    resolution='h')

shp_info = m.readshapefile('singapore_shapefile',
                            'singapore',
                            drawbounds=True)
```

However with cartopy, i get a blank with a dot in the middle.
[image]

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

# define map extent
lllat=1.1497
urlat=1.5133
lllon=103.5822
urlon=104.1579

# Set up cartopy instance
m = ccrs.Mercator()
ax = plt.axes(projection=m)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 10)

reader = shpreader.Reader("singapore_shapefile")
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(reader.geometries(), m, facecolor="w", 
                               edgecolor='black', lw=1)
ax.add_feature(shape_feature)

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Shapefile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1suB-VD65bmwesJo01mAvVUolRReWUkdV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

two things to note:

1. You need to set the map extent, otherwise, the area of interest is too small for the whole world.
2. ShapelyFeature function needs the projection for shapefile rather than the map.

Below is the modified code.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define map extent
lllat=1.1497
urlat=1.5133
lllon=103.5822
urlon=104.1579

# Set up cartopy instance
m = ccrs.Mercator()
ax = plt.axes(projection=m)

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 10)


extent=[lllon,urlon,lllat,urlat]
ax.set_extent(extent)

reader = shpreader.Reader("singapore_shapefile")
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(reader.geometries(), ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor="w",
                               edgecolor='black', lw=1)
ax.add_feature(shape_feature)

plt.savefig("singapore.png")
```

And here is the output plot.

[image]